# Tomcat maxThreads instantly reached: what is using these threads from the thread pool

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, threadpool

We have the situation that currentThreadCount and currentThreadsBusy are **stable** at around 90. Then a very sharp increase untill maxThreads (200) occurs which basically renders the system useless for new requests.
**Question: how can I see what is using the threads?**
Basically what classes are using the threads.
Is it also possible to see this retrospectively?

---

Note to underlying problem:
And attack can be excluded. There are other proposals what might happen

- DB might not release threads due to some reasons
- A rarely used functionality might run amok, generation endless requests

Note also that the problem disappears after about 20 minutes, which incidentally is the session timeout.

Answer (score 0):

If your Tomcat runs under a Linux server, you can check all the running threads depending on your webapp using the command `kill -3 [pid of your webapp]`. It will dump all the current threads and their status (and maybe where they are hanging) in the catalina.out of your webapp.

Answer (score 0):

Use a java agent like [glowroot](https://glowroot.org/) for a breakdown of what your threads are doing.